# Problema para descargar XLSX con AJAX usando blob

Tags: php, jquery, excel

Estoy intentando descargar un archivo xlsx, pero genera una planilla a la cual no puedo acceder con un editor, estoy usando la siguiente llamada ajax:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "./?action=export_excel",
      data: parametros,
      beforeSend: function(data) {
        $("#loader").html("<img src='res/images/ajax-loader.gif'>");
      },
      //console.log(data);
      success: function(data) {
        let today = new Date();
        let dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        let mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
        let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        today = `${mm}_${dd}_${yyyy}`;
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = downloadUrl;
        a.download = `Vencimientos_${today}.xlsx`;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        $("#loader").html("");
    }
});
```

PHP

```
  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
 
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'hello world!');

  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Hoja 1');

  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="helloworld.xlsx"');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
  
  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
  $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

El código PHP funciona por ese lado no creo que sea el problema.

Comment: No muestra ningún mensaje de error en la terminal? Al indicarle desde PHP `Content-Disposition`, le estás diciendo al navegador que lo descargue por default. Dado que estás generando un link de descarga y automáticamente le haces click, solo agrega `a.target = '_blank';`, y con eso no creo que sea necesario lo del `Blob`

Comment: @HammerffallBK no muestra nada la terminar, si no me funciona bajaré a xls, el a.href cómo lo dejo?

Comment: Espera que pase por desapercibido que está dentro de una llamada ajax.

Comment: @HammerffallBK perdón no entendí?

Comment: Olvida lo anterior. Ya que tienes `downloadUrl` intenta con `window.open(downloadUrl)` debería disparar la descarga

Comment: @HammerffallBK descarga el archivo sin extensión, le agregué el .xlsx y no lo puedo abrir con open office, tengo otros archivos xlsx que sí los abre

Comment: Mira el ejemplo de está página. Se parece a lo que estabas haciendo en un inicio.
https://medium.com/@danny.pule/export-json-to-csv-file-using-javascript-a0b7bc5b00d2
`function exportCSVFile`

Comment: @Hammerffallbk con csv funciona

Answer (score 1):

Funciona perfecto, solo agregue esta linea a mi codigo ajax y funciono perfecto  **xhrFields:{responseType: 'blob'}** gracias por compartir

Answer (score 0):

finalmente lo solucioné usando la siguiente instrucción ajax:

```
await $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "./?action=export_excel",
      data: parametros,
      beforeSend: function(data) {
        $("#loader").html("<img src='res/images/ajax-loader.gif'>");
      },    
      xhrFields:{responseType: 'blob'},
      //console.log(data);
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        let today = new Date();
        let dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        let mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
        let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        today = `${mm}_${dd}_${yyyy}`;
        var blob = data;
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = downloadUrl;
        a.download = `Vencimientos_${today}.xlsx`;
        a.target = '_blank';
        a.click();
        $("#loader").html("");

      }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo he realizado de la siguiente forma, de acuerdo al comentario anterior, salió a la perfección agregando "xhrFields:{responseType: 'blob'},"

```js
function reporte_excel() {
  var txt_fechaincio = $("#txt_fechaincio").val();
  var txt_fechafin = $("#txt_fechafin").val();
  var estado = $("#combo_estado_reporte").val();
  var an_o = $("#combo_anio_documento").val();

  console.log(txt_fechaincio);
  console.log(txt_fechafin);
  console.log(estado);
  console.log(an_o);
  console.log($("#txtnombre_principal_usuario").val());

  var datos = new FormData();
  datos.append("fecha_inicio", txt_fechaincio);
  datos.append("fecha_final", txt_fechafin);
  datos.append("estado", estado);
  datos.append("an_o", an_o);

  $.ajax({
    url: "reporteexcel.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    xhrFields: {
      responseType: "blob"
    },
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      setTimeout(function() {
        var dlbtn = document.getElementById("dlbtn");
        /* var file = new Blob([result], { type: "text/xlsx" }); */
        var file = result;
        dlbtn.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        dlbtn.download = "myfile.xls";
        $("#mine").click();
      }, 2000);
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: Diria que básicamente es la misma respuesta que ya existia, es un duplicado.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/323482)